# How to use tag filtering in Atlas

Tags: java, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

New to the [Atlas](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas) project (and also to Java), I am trying some things out. I am looking for the preferred way to combine the instructions given [here](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/tree/dev/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/atlas/tags/filters#tag-filtering) and [here](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/tree/dev/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/atlas/geography/atlas#filtering-an-atlas) to apply tag filtering on an Atlas.

Would the below be a good approach or is there a better alternative?

```java
String definition = "highway->residential";
final TaggableFilter filter = TaggableFilter.forDefinition(definition);
final Optional<Atlas> predicateAtlas = atlas.subAtlas(filter::test, AtlasCutType.SOFT_CUT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work and produce an other Atlas that contains all elements with `highway=residential`. It is important to note that Atlas has to follow feature integrity (i.e. an `Edge` cannot exist without its end `Node`s) which mean some features without the tag you specified here might still be pulled in (connected `Node`s, or parent `Relation`s for example).

Another way to only get the features that are tagged `highway=residential` would be to not force them to be fed back to an Atlas, but just printed, or handled with a custom function of your choice:

```
String definition = "highway->residential";
final TaggableFilter filter = TaggableFilter.forDefinition(definition);
atlas.entities(filter).forEach(entity -> ...);
```